# sql indexing and performance tuning

Tags: sql

I am new to sql but i am learning, I have a forum were people can search for a location using radius and latitudes, the site is loading pretty slow would indexing the search fields be appropriate? I have read that indexs should not be used on table that under go updates and creates yet I do not know what other things I can do to improve performance. I was thinking of maybe creating an identical table with the same information and using that only for searches with an index.

```
"Select * from threads where latitudes >= @ThirtyLatMin AND @ThirtyLatMax >= latitudes AND longitudes >= @ThirtyLonMin AND @ThirtyLonMax>=longitudes order by activities desc"
```

Comment: If you are talking about the first page being very slow, then the issue should be resolved at some other level than SQL may be you can check startup code, may be images on that page can be reduced in size without loosing acceptable quality, for searching, yes it would be a good idea to index those columns used in searches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any modern RDBMS should be able to handle a few indexes on a given table; while it's true that index maintenance has a cost during table INSERTs and UPDATEs, that cost is generally outweighed by appropriate index utilization during a SELECT statement (and other queries).

Some general tips, based on your question (and sample query):

1. Only return the data you need; using SELECT * in a query is usually a red flag when performance tuning, because it means the coder didn't take the time to spell out what was needed by the calling application.  If you're returning a bunch of data that you're not using, you're holding your performance back.
2. Once you've specified the columns to be returned, try to "cover" them with an index; in other words, make an index column that contains all of the information necessary to satisfy the query.  Note that this becomes a balancing act when dealing with multiple different queries (different columns) that hit the same table.   Too many indexes on a table increases the cost (see header), and may eventually outweigh the benefits. Note that different RDBMS's have different ways of dealing with this; for example, Microsoft SQL Server uses an INCLUDE syntax to represent broad, multi-column indexes in a covering capacity without significant overhead.
3. Index not only the columns returned, but make the first column of your indexes be the columns used in your WHERE clause.  From the example above, I'd put an index that started with latitude and longitude and included the remaining necessary columns.
4. Whenever possible, move sorting out of the database.  SORTS are expensive operations, and unless you're using it to assist in filtering data (i.e, TOP N searches), you'll probably see an improvement by moving it out of SQL.

Comment: thank you for that explanation that really cleared alot.

Answer (score 0):

> I have read that indexs should not be used on table that under go updates and creates

I would love to see where you have read that because that is incorrect.  Indexes are crucial to performance.

Please go read http://use-the-index-luke.com for a good introduction to indexes in SQL.